# How does DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN work?

Tags: linux, database, oracle, sqlplus

I have been reading this documentation and I understand based on the Oracle doc, you can access Oracle XML by assigning ACL to a host DB user. I am having difficulty understanding how to get this to work.

```
 BEGIN
 DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.CREATE_ACL(
 acl => 'testacl.xml',
 description => 'test xml',
 principal => 'PYTEST',
 is_grant => TRUE,
 privilege => 'connect');
 END;
 /

BEGIN DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.ASSIGN_ACL
 acl => 'testacl.xml',
 host => 'host ip address',
 lower_port => 80);
 END;
 /
```

I created this successfully, I tried

```
select * from dba_network_acls;

HOST
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
LOWER_PORT UPPER_PORT
---------- ----------
ACL
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ACLID
--------------------------------
host ip address
        80         80
/sys/acls/testacl.xml
404314DC2946ECE1E053106210330FC1
```

So obviously it has created the xml file. I went to the sys folder but can't find acls folder.

All this is done on a linux machine, via sqlplus. My ultimate goal is to get something like shown in

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14259/xdb16fol.htm#BCJBHCBJ

Figure 20-4.

I want to be able to navigate through the DB folders of this machine if I copy pasted the http://host:port  on the address bar, but obviously I am missing something which is why I am asking here.

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to what needs to be done to achieve this?

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand what you're trying to accomplish.  Your link is talking about using XML DB which is utterly different than using an ACL.   Yes, the ACL information happens to be in an XML document and XML DB has XML in the name.  But that's about the extent of the relationship.

Comment: So the two are not the same at all??? I am trying to accomplish what I said at the end there. "I want to be able to navigate through the DB folders of this machine if I copy pasted the http://host:port on the address bar" How is this doable?

Comment: When you say "db folders", are you talking about the operating system directory structure?   XML DB lets you expose data stored inside the database to the world as if it was a file system.  ACLs allow code running in the database to send network requests.  If you want to browse your operating system directory structure over the web, you'd want to install a web server of some sort and configure it to expose that information.  That's generally not recommended from a security perspective but it's certainly technically possible.

Comment: this does not do what you are trying to do.. the link you provided is NOT showing the file system.. it is showing the contents of the database and it just "looks like" a file system.